# Using Webdriver with Chrome -- missing Shared Libraries

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run webdriver, but I keep getting the following error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-0-41 ~]$ sudo ./chromedriver 
./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: 
 libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to `yum` this missing dependencies? Or what seems to be the issue here? This is using the `Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09.1 (HVM)` Distribution.

Answer (score -1):

chrome driver can't run by itself. You can run it via code only